# trigger Controller scope from directive AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a `TimelineController` that has a `publish` function on the scope, that will send some data to the server.

My timeline is composed by 2 `directives`

- timeline (Element)
- share-post (Element)

I would like to be able to call from the `share-post` directive the `publish` function on my `TimelineController` is that possible?.

**Controller**

```
function TimelineController($scope,TimelineService)
    {
        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.publish = function(wall_type,wall_id,text,video,image) {
            console.log('click controller');
            TimelineService.publishPost(wall_type,wall_id,text,video,image).$promise.then(function(result){
               $scope.posts.push(result.response);
            });
        };
    }
```

**Timeline Directive:**

```
function timelineDirective() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                type: '@',
                ids: '@',
                postime: '&',
                posts: '='
            },
            templateUrl:"/js/templates/timeline/post-tmpl.html",
            controller: function($scope,$element) {

                this.type = $element.attr('type');
                this.ids = $element.attr('ids');
            }
        }
    };
```

**Timeline Directive Template**

```
<ol class="timeline" ng-init="postime({wall_type:type,wall_id:ids})">
    <li>
       <share-post></share-post>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
       {{post.text}}
    </li>
</ol>
```

**SharePost Directive:** From this directive I would like call the publish on the `TimelineController`

```
function sharePost() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            require: "^timeline",
            templateUrl:"/js/templates/timeline/share-tmpl.html",
            link: function($scope,$element,$attr,ctrl) {
                $scope.pub = function() {

                    // This does not work because it call the parent directive
                    // Instead of controller
                    $scope.publish(ctrl.type, ctrl.ids, $scope.text);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

**Sharepost Directive Template**

```
<div class="module comment">
    <div class="content">
        <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="text" placeholder="What is going on..." rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="pub()"> Share</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I think you should either inject the TimelineService service directly into your directive or inject the "publish" function into the scope of your directive using attributes

Comment: I would like avoid to inject the Service to the directive

Comment: @Fabrizio, let me get this straight, do you want to fire a click event on the controller from a directive?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper I want fire the function `$scope.publish` in the controller from an event `click` from the directive.

Answer (score 1):

well you use your directive just to bind the event click from the controller, something like:

```
angular.module('module').directive('sharePost', [
        function(){
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                    var clickAction = attr.clickAction;
                    element.bind('click',function (event) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction);
                    });
                }
            };
    }]);
```

**html**

```
 <a sharePost click-action="publish(wall_type,wall_id,text,video,image)"> publish</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seem interesting but I didn't get where that `function` come from, that function was meaning the `publish` function on the controller? Thanks

Comment: sorry I just copied and pasted it from your code, forgot to reference the controller scope, that's just your publish function

Comment: Ok, now make more sense, I'll try that it sounds good to me :)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work because the directive still doesn't know about the `publish` function. That `sharePost` directive is  a child directive of another directive

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive to have an extra item in the scope like this `onPublish: "@"` then in your html you can pass a pointer to the controller function you want to invoke like this:

```
 <share-post on-publish="publish"></share-post>
```

to call this from the directive you have to do:

```
$scope.onPublish()(ctrl.type, ctrl.ids, $scope.text)
```

Comment: This way does not work, because how you can see the `share-post` directive is child of `timeline` if I pass the `publish` method how you showed it try to get the parent directive `publish` I guess.

Comment: I missed the nested directives, you can achieve calling the controller method by passing the function from the controller to the parent directive, and then from there to the child one. But this is a bit nasty. 
Another way would be to have a service injected (a new one) in the child directive and in the controller, so you can use that to communicate

Comment: Yhea you explained what i was saying better then me, it is nasty to pass from parent directive to child directive. Thanks a lots, may you show a small example on how with a service I can put in communication, directive and controller?

Comment: Now that I think, it would not be wrong to declare which method you want called once a click in the directive happens, as long as the attribute is named accordingly, e.g. `on-post-clicked` or something  of that sorts

Comment: That's ok but I don't think this way is the more correct way: http://pastebin.com/Ytjbjq9x because I pass the `publish` scope on the `timeline` directive that it doesn't need of it but is just a bridge to let that `scope` available to the child directive. Correct me if I'm wrong, and if this solution is fine

Comment: Can you create a plunkr with your sample? I can fix it there.
You are creating a single scope on the parent directive, so you'd be passing the function as a callback there only. If you provide a plunkr I can show how to do it there